# scp from Windows Server to Unix server works but not the other way around

Tags: windows, ssh, scp

I installed OpenSSH on my Windows Server machine to use SSH. To test this out, I ran this command from my windows server.

```
scp test.txt user@unixserver.company.com:/path
```

Which worked, I can see the file on unix via putty. However, if I run this command on the unix server:

```
scp index.txt user@windowserver.company.com:/path
```

It doesn't work. It hangs for a long time and eventually I get:

```
ssh: connect to host windowserver.company.com port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection
```

Comment: Check your firewall.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I set a new Inbound rule for TCP port 22 but still doesn't work

Comment: Did you install OpenSSH as native Windows program or within a WSL1/WSL2 environment?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your firewall has the configured port open.
2. Ensure the server is listening on the configured port. For example, if your server is configured to listen on port 22, run `netstat -ano | findstr ":22"`
3. Make sure the traffic is allowed on any firewalls between the subnets if applicable.
4. Microsoft's documentation is pretty good for OpenSSH. Particularly, check the steps here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse#start-and-configure-openssh-server